# ObjectDataSource Insert throws an Error (using Business Objects)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

**Quick overview**

- Trying to insert a Business Object using ObjectDataSource (on a GridView)
- Get the following Error

ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' has no values to insert. Check that the 'values' dictionary contains values.

**Project SetUp**

- Person - simple dummy Business Object (Name and Age)
- PersonBinder - Holds the methods for the Object DataSource (Select and Insert in this case)
- InsertGrid - simple Grid (inherits GridView) add an "Add" button on the Footer, which inturn calls the DataSource's Insert
- Default - ASPX page, holds the Grid and Datasource, (applies Insert params to the DataSorce)

Note I added TODO comments around, what i think are key areas

**The Code**

*Person Binder*
Missing out the person (its get 2 properties) here is the binder

```
/// <summary>
/// A binding Class.
/// </summary>
public class PersonBinder
{

    public IEnumerable<Person> Select()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.Name = "Name " + i.ToString();
            person.Age = i;
            people.Add(person);
        }

        return people;
    }


    public void Insert(Person p)
    {
        //TODO: the Insert Method
        //errors before this.
    }
}
```

*InsertGrid*

```
public class InsertGrid : GridView
{
    protected override void OnInit(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        ShowFooter = true;
        DataBind();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// here to handle button clicks.
    /// </summary>
    private void ModeCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Add":

                //ObjectDataSource objectDataSource = DataSource as ObjectDataSource;
                ObjectDataSource objectDataSource = Parent.FindControl(DataSourceID) as ObjectDataSource;

                if (objectDataSource != null)
                {
                    //TODO: Errors HERE!
                    objectDataSource.Insert();
                }
                break;

        }


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RowDataBound"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="T:System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs"/> that contains event data.</param>
    protected override void OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDataBound(e);
        //add an insert button
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {

            ImageButton ibtnAdd = new ImageButton();
            ibtnAdd.ID = "Add";
            ibtnAdd.CommandName = "Add";
            ibtnAdd.ToolTip = "Add new Item";
            ibtnAdd.ImageAlign = ImageAlign.AbsMiddle;
            ibtnAdd.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
            ibtnAdd.CausesValidation = true;
            ibtnAdd.Command += ModeCommand;
            ibtnAdd.Enabled = true;
            e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ibtnAdd);

        }
    }
}
```

*Default HTML*

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataObjectTypeName="GridViewSample.Person" InsertMethod="Insert" 
        SelectMethod="Select" TypeName="GridViewSample.PersonBinder">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
</div>
<br />
<cc1:InsertGrid ID="InsertGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
    </Columns>
</cc1:InsertGrid>
</form>
```

*Default CodeBehind*

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        //TODO: here is the insert PARAMs. what am i missing.
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("Name", "");
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("Age", "0");
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Tried this too
        IDataSource ds = ObjectDataSource1;
        DataSourceView view = ds.GetView(InsertGrid1.DataMember);
        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("Name", "");
        //values.Add("Age", "0");

        view.Insert(values, delegate { return false; });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you deriving your own GridView control and not just using it out 'of the bag' ?

Comment: this is been simplifed, as the actaul grid has more specialised features (which would cloud the issue). the Add button has been added to encapsulate some of the functionality in one place (work in progress its a POC)

Also its not the Grid, which is the issue, its my understanding of the datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does actually work.

```
IDataSource ds = ObjectDataSource1;
DataSourceView view = ds.GetView(InsertGrid1.DataMember);        
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();        
values.Add("Name", "");        
//values.Add("Age", "0");        
view.Insert(values, delegate { return false; });
```

what I needed to do was to remove/replace the

```
//TODO: Errors HERE!                   
objectDataSource.Insert();
```